# Getting value of anchor tag from repeater?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, repeater

I have a regular html anchor link that is bound to an Id column.  I want to loop through the repeater and get the value of the Id column, but can't figure out how.  I have some code below my repeater markup.  I can't figure out how to do it with just a client side anchor tag.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repSearchResults" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
           <td><a href='<%#Eval("Id")%>'><%#Eval("Id")</a></td>
        </tr>
</asp:Repeater>

Protected Sub btnGetIds_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    For Each item As RepeaterItem In repSearchResults.Items
        If (item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item) Then

           'Get Id here

        End If



    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a hidden field inside each template:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hid" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("Id")%>' />
    ...
</ItemTemplate>
```

and then inside the loop:

```
If item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Then
    Dim ctrl As HiddenField = TryCast(item.FindControl("hid"), HiddenField)
        If ctrl IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim id As String = ctrl.Value
            ' do something with the id
    End If
End If
```

Comment: This is an option too, but between your solution and Josh's, is there an advantage to either one?

Comment: @Xaisoft, if later you decide to use something else as text of the anchor, other than the id, Josh's solution will no longer work whereas with the hidden field it is guaranteed that you will always get the id.

Comment: Excellent point.  Josh's solution worked, but I will try your solution now.

Comment: I decided to go with this solution because of the fact that you pointed out that if the anchor tag changes to another control, the hidden field will still work and I did not have to change to existing anchor tag already (adding runat and and id).  There is one issue that I had though.  When I looped through the repeater, I noticed that every other item was an AlternatingItem, so it was actually skipping those.  I added a check to process AlternatingItems, but I thought it is only an AlternatingItem if you specify an AlternatingItem template.  Does the Repeater do this automatically?

Answer (score 2):

You would need to make the anchor runat=server, name it, and then access it with the FindControl method.

Comment: I was thinking I needed to do this, but wasn't sure if there was another way.  Thanks.

Comment: I'll try it out and let you know.